# Problems downloading packages using "ptxdist get"

Tags: linux, build, proxy, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm trying to compile Linux for an embedded system. I'm using `ptxdist` command to build the system.

My colleague told me to use `ptxdist get` so we can get all dependencies downloaded before we start compiling.
We also sit behind a proxy and my `/etc/environment` is configured with the http/https/ftp proxy (same IP and port for all), as well as apt (meaning that `wget` works fine without extra parameters)

**PROBLEM:**
Running `ptxdist get` **will download some** of the packages, others **it will just not download** and the following error appears *(example for 2 packages)*:

Here is an example when it worked fine:

```
---------------------------
target: cmake-3.13.4.tar.gz
---------------------------

--2019-07-23 20:54:28--  https://cmake.org/files/v3.13/cmake-3.13.4.tar.gz
Connecting to <PROXY IP HERE>:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 8617881 (8.2M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: '/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/src/cmake-3.13.4.tar.gz.RSjrC7k7mC'

/home/xxxxxxx/x 100%[===================>]   8.22M  2.00MB/s    in 4.7s

2019-07-23 20:54:34 (1.75 MB/s) - '/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/src/cmake-3.13.4.tar.gz.RSjrC7k7mC' saved [8617881/8617881]
```

And here an example when it failed:

```
-----------------------
target: lzo-2.08.tar.gz
-----------------------

--2019-07-23 20:55:13--  http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/download/lzo-2.08.tar.gz
Connecting to <PROXY IP HERE>:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 502 Proxy Error ( The specified network name is no longer available.  )
2019-07-23 20:55:13 ERROR 502: Proxy Error ( The specified network name is no longer available.  ).

--2019-07-23 20:55:13--  http://www.pengutronix.de/software/ptxdist/temporary-src/lzo-2.08.tar.gz
Connecting to <PROXY IP HERE>:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 502 Proxy Error ( The specified network name is no longer available.  )
2019-07-23 20:55:13 ERROR 502: Proxy Error ( The specified network name is no longer available.  ).

make: *** [/home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/src/lzo-2.08.tar.gz] Error 1

Could not download package
URL: http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/download/lzo-2.08.tar.gz

/usr/local/lib/ptxdist-2019.03.1/rules/post/ptxd_make_world_get.make:17: recipe for target '/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/src/lzo-2.08.tar.gz' failed
```

Even if I repeat `ptxdist get`, it stops at the same exact package that fails.

**BUT:**
If I just use

```
wget http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/download/lzo-2.08.tar.gz
```

it downloads the file just fine, same happens to ANY other package that fails, using the URL that shows up above.
When I run `ptxdist get` then it moves on to other downloads as it sees the file already there, and then hangs on the next download that failes.

**ALSO TRIED:**
I also tried to run `ptxdist setup` and configure the proxy there. Nothing changes in the terminal, so no luck...

**ALSO TRIED:**
I also wrote a script that takes package names using `ptxdist print PACKAGES`, then gets the URL using `ptxdist package-info <PKG>` then downloads the file via `wget <URL>`, this solved most part of the errors while running `ptxdist get` as `wget` works fine, but it seems that there are many other packages that are needed and not listed with `ptxdist print PACKAGES`...

Any idea what is wrong and what can I do?
*Since I'm supposed to automate this task, there is no way manual interaction (for using `wget` on failing packages) is an option...*

Comment: Does `wget` use the same proxy?

Comment: Yes it does. wget uses the proxy set in /etc/environment (also in `env`), which is the same one.

Comment: Can you tell details about the proxy? Does it do strange things when you download files in a web browser? (I remember a company proxy that replaced all download links with a redirection to a page created by the proxy showing a progress indication first and finally a download button. The solution in this case was that the IT department switched off the proxy for my Linux PC.) Does the error occur only for unencrypted connections? (`https:` vs. `http:`)

Comment: @Bodo I dont know any details, apart from the `ptxdist get` only taking few files... I ended up making a small script that will run `ptxdist get` and uses `tee` to show and also save the results on a file, then parse the file and look for all the lines with `^URL:`, extract the URL and then just download the files using `wget`... Its stupid but it works and I get all the fines one way or the other.

Comment: @Bodo, I have been using this proxy for almost 3 years, and only now I faced such problem. Although it is the first time using ptxdist, and my colleagues say they have the same issue...

Comment: Maybe you should ask your IT department (or the responsible person) for help or for more information.